# Trying to extract the numbers from an output of Raspberry PI DHT 22 sensor

Tags: bash, sed, raspberry-pi

The DHT 22 outputs the Temp and Humidity as such

Temp=24.8*  Humidity=46.6%

now i am trying to use 'sed' to extract

1)  the temperature 24.8

and

2) the humidity 46.6

in bash commandline so i can process further as a variable $t and $h.

I am having trouble to build the sed to extract the first number (temp)
and the second number (humidity). Can you please help me. After several hours i am lost now.

Answer (score 1):

Do a grep and sed from the file wehre

```
       1) grep -ozP 'Temp=....' hum.txt | sed -e 's/Temp=//g'
```

the same way with Humidity.

[image: demo screenshoot]